# Error: Cannot find module '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread'

Tags: webpack

I keep getting this error while running Webpack. I have deleted `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and reinstalled my packages multiple times to no avail. `ls node_modules/@babel/` shows no subfolder for the `@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread` package.

What is the problem, and how do I resolve it?

**Stack trace** (Edited to remove redundancy)

```
Error: Cannot find module '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread' from '~/industrial'
at Function.resolveSync [as sync] (~/node_modules/resolve/lib/sync.js:89:15)
at resolveStandardizedName (~/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:101:31)
at resolvePlugin (~/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:54:10)
at reduce (~/node_modules/babel-merge/dist/index.js:21:26)
at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
at mergeArray (~/node_modules/babel-merge/dist/index.js:20:36)
at babelMerge (~/node_modules/babel-merge/dist/index.js:40:19)
at values.reduce (~/node_modules/babel-merge/dist/index.js:60:26)
at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
at Function.value (~/node_modules/babel-merge/dist/index.js:58:49)
at Function.generate (~/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/BabelConfig.js:11:22)
at Object.babel (~/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/config.js:121:45)
at JavaScript.webpackRules (~/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/JavaScript.js:76:41)
at ComponentFactory.applyRules (~/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/ComponentFactory.js:155:23)
at Mix.listen.rules (~/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/ComponentFactory.js:66:48)
at events.(anonymous function).forEach.handler (~/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Dispatcher.js:34:47)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at Dispatcher.fire (~/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Dispatcher.js:34:28)
at Mix.dispatch (~/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Mix.js:118:25)
at WebpackConfig.buildRules (~/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/builder/WebpackConfig.js:90:13)
at WebpackConfig.build (~/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/builder/WebpackConfig.js:23:14)
at Object.<anonymous> (~/node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js:29:38)
at Module._compile (~/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
at require (~/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
at WEBPACK_OPTIONS (~/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:114:13)
at requireConfig (~/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:116:6)
at ~/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:123:17
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at module.exports (~/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:121:15)
at yargs.parse (~/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:71:45)
at Object.parse (~/node_modules/webpack-cli/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:567:18)
```

**package.json**

```
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.0",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
        "@kazupon/vue-i18n-loader": "^0.4.1",
        "browser-sync": "^2.26.7",
        "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
        "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.2.1",
        "eslint": "^5.16.0",
        "eslint-loader": "^2.2.1",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.2.3",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.26.3",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "vue-template-compiler": "2.6.10"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.27",
        "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.12.1",
        "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^0.1.9",
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.1.1",
        "@websanova/vue-auth": "^2.21.14-beta",
        "axios": "^0.19.2",
        "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
        "bootstrap-vue": "^2.7",
        "camelcase": "^5.3.1",
        "clipboard": "^2.0.6",
        "clone-deep": "^4.0.1",
        "core-js": "^3.6.4",
        "deepmerge": "^4.2.2",
        "del": "^5.1.0",
        "driver.js": "^0.9.8",
        "dropzone": "^5.7.0",
        "echarts": "^4.7.0",
        "es6-promise": "^4.2.8",
        "file-saver": "^2.0.1",
        "fuse.js": "^3.6.1",
        "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
        "jsonlint": "^1.6.3",
        "jszip": "^3.2.2",
        "less": "^3.11.1",
        "less-loader": "^5.0.0",
        "mime-types": "^2.1.26",
        "moment": "^2.24.0",
        "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
        "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
        "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
        "numeral": "^2.0.6",
        "overlayscrollbars": "^1.11.0",
        "overlayscrollbars-vue": "^0.2.1",
        "path-to-regexp": "^3.2.0",
        "portal-vue": "^2.1.7",
        "query-string": "^6.11.1",
        "ramda": "^0.26.1",
        "raw-loader": "^4.0.0",
        "resize-observer-polyfill": "^1.5.1",
        "screenfull": "^4.2.1",
        "snake-case": "^3.0.3",
        "sortablejs": "^1.10.2",
        "trim": "0.0.1",
        "tui-editor": "^1.4.10",
        "vue": "2.6.10",
        "vue-axios": "^2.1.5",
        "vue-clipboard2": "^0.3.1",
        "vue-count-to": "^1.0.13",
        "vue-i18n": "^8.15.5",
        "vue-multiselect": "^2.1.6",
        "vue-router": "^3.1.6",
        "vue-splitpane": "^1.0.6",
        "vuedraggable": "^2.23.2",
        "vuelidate": "^0.7.5",
        "vuex": "3.1.0",
        "vuex-router": "^1.1.5",
        "webpack": "^4.43.0",
        "xlsx": "^0.14.5"
    },
```

Comment: That's not listed in your dependencies, why *would* it be there?

Comment: It's a dependency for something. There are references to it in package-lock.

Comment: Removing the one I obviously can't install, `@netshapers/resources`, I don't see `@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread` in `package-lock.json` (or `./node_modules/@babel`). Please give a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

`laravel-mix` and `laravel-mix-bundle-analyzer` were missing as dependencies.